# How to save the report made by solver in pulp as a text file

Tags: python, pulp

I want to save the report( if you run it for example in vscode it shows a report in the terminal) made by a solver like CBC in python's pulp package as a text file automatically . Any ideas? Is it even possible? I've read the documentation but I haven't found anything. This is some part from the report I mean:

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.9.0
Build Date: Feb 12 2015
```

This is another part:

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                3333.15276400
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               1
Time (CPU seconds):             0.01
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.03   (Wallclock seconds):       0.02
```

And it continues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't read hard enough. There's a `logPath` argument for storing the cbc log:
https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html#pulp.apis.COIN_CMD